# Why can't jQuery ajaxSend create data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

See below code.

In `ajaxSend` I can edit or add `s.data`, but jQuery sends request without additional data if I don't provide any other data in $.post().

Any suggestions?

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    print_r($_POST);
} else { ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ajaxSend(function (e, xhr, s) {
            s.data = s.data ? s.data+'&' : '';
            s.data += 'my_value=1';
        })

        $.post('/test.php'); // empty $_POST
        $.post('/test.php', {value: 0}); // $_POST with value and my_value
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm seeing it properly append `my_value=1`. What are you seeing on your end?

Comment: @DanielT. 
in second request
Array(
    [value] => 0
    [my_value] => 1
)

Comment: Isn't that what you want it to be?

Comment: @DanielT. Trouble with first request, where I can't see `$_POST['my_value']`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used jQuery for some while now and thus haven't used its ajax stuff, either, but after having a look at its source the chosen event looks like to be improper for what you want to do.

- The documentation is giving examples on logging requests using `ajaxSend` event, only.
- The code in jQuery's `src/ajax.js` is firing `ajaxSend` **after** creating (and most obviously starting) the request. Apparently, the event is dispatched synchronously. Thus, your event handler happens to handle a request that has been started already, but which is delayed until current execution environment - the one in which request was started and your event handler is invoked - has ended prior to actually processing the request in background. That's why it is possible to modify any data attached to the running request due to accessing object by reference, but it isn't possible to add data since jQuery didn't attach it to the request before. And it isn't using `s.data` after event has been dispatched. There are just a few things done then and that is mostly related to handling timeouts etc.

So, neither documentation advises to use `ajaxSend` for this kind of request filtering, nor does code show any support for that. But while checking the code I stumbled over some support for what is called *prefilters*. Maybe you should stick with that instead and check out the documentation on [$.ajaxPrefilter](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/).

Comment: Yes this callback works perfectly in ajaxPrefilter. But I reallty surprised about the inability to attach data.